# How can I run the profiler from the command line?

Tags: matlab, profiler

I know that I can use the profiler from the GUI

> Desktop-> Profiler

Is there any way to run by a command?

Comment: take a peek at [profile](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/profile.html)

Comment: 'profview' brings the profiler GUI to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the command

```
profile on
```

and to stop profiling , you use:

```
profile off
```

See [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html) for more info.

Answer (score 4):

The notation is

```
profile on
%% your functions here
profile off
```

Many of the arguments for the command "profile" have a hyphen though, just not on and off. See [matlab's documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html). You can also use the command:

```
profile('info')
```

to get a structure containing your results, if you're working entirely on the command line, and not using the viewer.